# Strange behaviour when printing execution time using Sys.time()

Tags: r

I have the sample code below:

```
f <- function(x) {
  v = 0
  start = Sys.time()
  for (i in 1:x) {
    v = v + 1
  }
  end = Sys.time()
  print(end-start)
  print(paste0("f() took: ", end-start))
}

f(10)
```

The 2 outputs are:

1. `Time difference of 5.960464e-06 secs`
2. `"f() took: 5.96046447753906e-06"`

My question is why when used with `paste0` the output is different.

### Edit:

If one wish to get the units of time do the following:

```
print(paste0("f() took: ", end-start, " ", units(end-start)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `?print.difftime`:

> The print() method calls these “time differences”.

It's an in-built method for print that displays differences in dates in this format.

```
class(Sys.Date()-Sys.Date()+1)
[1] "difftime"

class(paste(Sys.Date()-Sys.Date()+1))
[1] "character"
```

`paste0("f() took: ", end-start)` becomes a character class and so print will handle it differently